# How to change Pycharm2016.1 theme to Solarized Dark

Tags: pycharm

I have upgraded Pycharm2016.1 today and was looking to change theme to Solarized Dark but I could not see an option to change/add. Any one try doing same with Pycharm2016.1?

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51945983

Answer (score 12):

There is a solarized theme for IntelliJ on [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized). It also works with PyCharm.

All you need to do is:

1. download the above repo, unzip it
2. go to `File | Import Settings...`
3. specify the `setting.jar` file in the `intellij-colors-solarized` directory and click `OK`
4. restart PyCharm
5. go to `Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts` and choose one of the solarized themes

On PyCharm 2016.2 it works like a charm, so I think it should also work with 2016.1.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13949758)

Comment: just add detailed steps for solving the proposed question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the Solarized Dark theme, as well as other themes, from [here](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes).
2. On Pycharm, click on `File` > `Import Settings` and browse to the downloaded theme file and double click on it:

[image: browse to downloaded theme]

1. After double clicking on the theme file, a new window will appear, on this window, click on `Select All` and then click `OK`:

[image: Select Components to Import]

1. Restart Pycharm and you should have Solarized Dark set!

Enjoy :)

Comment: This solarized is horrible... the one Zichao posted from github is much nicer looking.